# How to define appearance order of items in bpy.props.EnumProperty?

Tags: python, panel

This question has been haunting me for quite a while. I need to set items in Enum in some specific order. Let's say, I have:

```
import bpy


class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Draw Panel in N-Panel"""
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "my enum"
    bl_label = "My Enum"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.column().prop(context.scene, "my_enum")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="My Enum", items={
        ("1","1","1",1),
        ("2","2","2",2),
        ("3","3","3",3),
        ("4","4","4",4),
        ("5","5","5",5),
    })
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_enum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Obviously I expect to get the same order of items in the EnumProperty in UI as in my_enum property: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But here is what I get instead:

[image]

My question is how can I actually control appearance order of the items in EnumProperty?

Comment: Sets are by definition unordered. Use a list (`[]`) or a tuple (`()`) instead of a set (`{}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

````
import bpy


class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Draw Panel in N-Panel"""
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "my enum"
    bl_label = "My Enum"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.column().prop(context.scene, "my_enum")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="My Enum",
        items=(
            ("1","1","1"),
            ("2","2","2"),
            ("3","3","3"),
            ("4","4","4"),
            ("5","5","5"),
        )
    )
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_enum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()

```
````